# Is it compulsory to support both ARM and Intel ( 32/64 ) bit architecture for all the Android App published on Google Play Store?

Tags: android

Do we need to support both ARM and Intel or any one arch library is acceptable by google play store.

As per Android Developer website :

https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit

Starting August 1, 2019, your apps published on Google Play will need to support 64-bit architectures.

For the ARM architecture, the 32-bit libraries are located in armeabi-v7a. The 64-bit equivalent is arm64-v8a.

For the x86 architecture, look for x86 for 32-bit and x86_64 for 64-bit.

Most Intel-powered Android devices has libhoudini - proprietary ARM translation layer for x86-powered Android devices. 
All ARM apps running on Intel devices

Example : ASUS ZenFone.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned *Most Intel-powered Android devices has libhoudini - proprietary ARM translation layer for x86-powered Android devices*. So in our cases, built binaries for WebRTC armeabi-v7a version was working fine on some arm64-v8a devices.

However, it was because of Intel core inside. And we didn't sure about stability on another vendors. For our case, we just had possibility to prebuilt all the binaries for the WebRTC library.

Comment: You all have shared all the 4 library ( 2 ARM - 32+ 64 bit) and (2 Intel -32 + 64 bit) along with the apk. Any specific devices in which you had validated the Intel libraries ( prefer device name /make) ?

Comment: @mail2subhajit I don't sure, which model, it was Motorola with Intel x32. We were using arm library, and it was working fine. But in later just bundled all the libs, from the WebRTC build, with all 4 libs for x32 and x64, for different archs.